# Difference in function argument between int pointer and int array

Tags: c++

What is the difference between taking as a function argument an int pointer or an int array in C++?

```
void arrayFunction1(int * x) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << x[i] << endl;
  }
}

void arrayFunction2(int x[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << x[i] << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  int dstdata[10];
  
  arrayFunction1(dstdata);
  arrayFunction2(dstdata);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Both results look the same to me.

Comment: `int[]` as a parameter type does not mean "array of `int`", it means "pointer to `int`". Your prototypes are equivalent, and both function arguments are equivalent to passing `&dstdata[0]`.

Comment: Yeah, they're exactly the same, which is an endless source of confusion for people thinking they'd be different and then wondering why `sizeof(x)` gives unexpected results.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Exactly. Why does sizeof(dstdata) return 40 and sizeof(x) return 8? I've learnt that to calculate the length of an array I I can calculate sizeof(array) / sizeof(type). This won't work in the function call.

Comment: An array in C++ is `std::array`. You should start with STL and go to pointers, C-arrays and other advanced stuff after you've learned the basics. A C++ array can be copied and passed to functions. Either learn C or C++, not both at the same time. That's confusing and leads to very bad practices.

Comment: It won't work because when you declare an array _as a function parameter_ (and only there), you're actually declaring a pointer. It's a weird quirk of the language that C++ inherited from C. You really should be using `std::array` instead of C arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are completely identical. In a function parameter `int x[]` is just another way of writing `int* x`. Even `int x[10]` is the same (the `10` is completely ignored).

Now why Kernighan and Ritchie (the inventors of C) thought this piece of deception was a good idea is another question. I guess they weren't thinking of all the people who have to learn the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what is considered the "best practice", considering the two notations are equivalent?

Comment: @RiccardoPerego The pointer version, it's honest about what `x` is.

Comment: @RiccardoPerego I'd argue that the best practice isn't to pass pointers at all, but to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: Or you could follow the standard library's approach and instead of passing a container directly, you pass a starting iterator and a sentinel value indicating the end of the range.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I just started learning C++ so I haven't got there yet. Was just wondering whether the two were equivalent.

Comment: @RiccardoPerego If you really want  `dstdata` to be an `int[10]`, pass it to functions wrapped in a `std::span`.

Comment: @RiccardoPerego unfortunately most tutorials and courses teach it the wrong way around. They start with stuff that is rarely used in real coding and keep the idomatic stuff for the later chapters. `std::array` and `std::vector` are the beginner-friendly counter parts for c-arrays.